# Filter out rows which the text on that current row is contained in the text of the following row

Tags: mysql, mariadb, select, mariadb-10.5

I wonder if it's possible, in a `SELECT`, to filter out rows which the text on that current row is contained in the text of the following row.

For example, image we log "searches" performed by a user, "as they type":

```
1  something I searched
2  another search
3  this
4  this is a
5  this is a third
6  this is a third search
7  fourth
8  fourth search
9  here's a ry
10 here's a typo
```

**Rows 3-6** are effectively the same - just the user was a bit "slow" typing it, so we saved multiple times.
**Rows 7-8** the same too.
**Rows 9-10** are the same, but there was a typo.

I am looking to do a `SELECT` that would return the following rows only:

```
1  something I searched
2  another search
6  this is a third search
8  fourth search
9  here's a ry
10 here's a typo
```

Is something like this possible?

Note - there's no guarantee at all that the IDs will be in a sequence for a specific user. So, I can't simply `JOIN` with the table itself, by the `id = id+1`. All I can do is `ORDER BY id` to get them in order.

Comment: In your `Searches` table do you have a way to identify which searches were performed by which user (e.g. a `UserId` column)?...or you don't care to break it out by user, and you just want to globally remove *repeatedly contained* searches?

Comment: Yeah, UserId is there. Basically I want to fetch searches performed by a user, but removing the redundant searches (those that are contained in others). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use a window function, specifically the [`LEAD()`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/lead/) function would make great use here like so:

```
-- Gets the following row's search text and compare it to the current row's search text to see if the following row starts with the current row's
WITH _SearchesMarkedAsRedundant
(
    SELECT 
        id, 
        userId,
        searchText,             
        IF(LEAD(searchText) OVER (PARTITION BY userId ORDER BY id) LIKE CONCAT(searchText, '%'), 1, 0) ​IsRedundantSearch
    FROM Searches
)

-- Returns only the rows whose following row did not start with this row's search text
SELECT id, userId, searchText
FROM _SearchesMarkedAsRedundant
WHERE IsRedundantSearch = 0
```

And if you wanted to globally remove redundant searches, despite which user inputted the search, you can remove the `PARTITION BY` clause of the window function like so `IF(LEAD(searchText) OVER (userId ORDER BY id) LIKE CONCAT(searchText, '%'), 1, 0) ​IsRedundantSearch`.

The above will accomplish the output from your given example. Note it specifically **only** looks at the next **1 row** (sorted by the id column) and checks if the that row **starts with** the same search text as the current row. You can make it do a full **contains** check instead by adding another wildcard `%` symbol to the front of the `searchText` in the `CONCAT()` operator like so `CONCAT('%', searchText, '%')`.

The `LEAD()` window function is the key to this solution here, as it can look-ahead at the column inputted by however many rows you specify. The default number of rows it looks-ahead is 1 but if you wanted to look at the 3rd row ahead instead of the next row, then `LEAD(searchText, 3)` would look-ahead by 3 rows.

Comment: Did anyone remove most of the comments that were in this post, like my Thank You reply? What's with all this censorship of non-offensive comments?...